# Ubuntu 9.10 resize screen size not resolution

Tags: display, ubuntu-9.10

My laptop LCD is damaged from one corner so want to reduce the size of screen about 1 inch from left but want to keep the highest available resolution which is 13xx x something.
I know this is possible but I don't know how - how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

[xrandr](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR) is probably going to be your best bet.